# Laravel 5.4 return full order in blade

Tags: php, laravel, relationship, laravel-5.4

I have been struggling with Laravel relationships. I am making an simple webshop. I have 4 important tables: order, orderrule, product and user.

I have inserted the order with laravel Shoppingcart this all went well. But now I want to get the full order back again so I can make an PDF file for it.

**This is my database design**: https://i.stack.imgur.com/nfPJy.png

**This is my order model:**

```
public function orderRules()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Order_rule::class, 'order_id', 'order_id');
}

public function locations()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Location::class, 'place_id');
}

public function users()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(User::class, 'user_id');
}
```

This is my Controller function:

```
public function orders()
{
    $user_id = Auth::id();

    $orders = Order::with('orderRules')->with('locations')->with('users')->where('user_id', $user_id)->get();

    dd($orders);

    return view('orders', [
        'orders' => $orders,
    ]);
}
```

And this is my result that I am getting from the dumpdata:

```
Collection {#239 ▼
  #items: array:4 [▼
    0 => Order {#224 ▶}
    1 => Order {#225 ▶}
    2 => Order {#226 ▼
      #connection: "mysql"
      #table: null
      #primaryKey: "id"
      #keyType: "int"
      +incrementing: true
      #with: []
      #withCount: []
      #perPage: 15
      +exists: true
      +wasRecentlyCreated: false
      #attributes: array:5 [▶]
      #original: array:5 [▶]
      #casts: []
      #dates: []
      #dateFormat: null
      #appends: []
      #events: []
      #observables: []
      #relations: array:3 [▼
        "orderRules" => Collection {#220 ▼
          #items: array:2 [▼
            0 => Order_rule {#244 ▼
              #connection: "mysql"
              #table: null
              #primaryKey: "id"
              #keyType: "int"
              +incrementing: true
              #with: []
              #withCount: []
              #perPage: 15
              +exists: true
              +wasRecentlyCreated: false
              #attributes: array:5 [▶]
              #original: array:5 [▼
                "id" => 23
                "order_id" => 521056
                "product_id" => 1
                "quantity" => 2
                "date" => "2017-06-16 14:21:22"
              ]
              #casts: []
              #dates: []
              #dateFormat: null
              #appends: []
              #events: []
              #observables: []
              #relations: []
              #touches: []
              +timestamps: true
              #hidden: []
              #visible: []
              #fillable: []
              #guarded: array:1 [▶]
            }
            1 => Order_rule {#245 ▶}
          ]
        }
        "locations" => Location {#233 ▶}
        "users" => User {#219 ▶}
      ]
      #touches: []
      +timestamps: true
      #hidden: []
      #visible: []
      #fillable: []
      #guarded: array:1 [▶]
    }
    3 => Order {#227 ▶}
  ]
}
```

I only want the **name of the product** via the orderRule table, but the orderRule join only gives the product_id. Can someone help me with this? Thanks in advance!

Comment: [Has Many Through](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent-relationships#has-many-through) relationship is what you want.

Comment: You do not need the order_id column on the orders table, related tables should reference the id directly. Also, follow naming conventions and user location_id instead of place_id for referencing the webshop.

Comment: @btl The id of a table is always unique right and every table needs a primary key? If I remove the order_id, 1 order can only have 1 product... Please correct my mistakes if I am wrong.

Comment: Not necessarily, you can have tables without indices (primary, unique, compsite, etc.). In that schema you linked, the order rules table is what links orders to products, so order 1 can link to product 1, product 2, product 3, etc. by creating separate order rules records for each.

Comment: aaahh alright that is a nice tip. I am going to change that!

Answer (score 0):

I would first add

```
protected $with = ['order', 'product'];
```

to your OrderRule model, that way the related order and produce information will always be eager loaded.

Then try this for pulling a user's orders:

```
$orders = Auth::user()->orders->with('locations')->get();
```

I wouldn't limit yourself to only the product name when retrieving orders also, it's not like the Product model is large and you may just need some of the additional data down the road.

Comment: I tried using your example. Ended up with querybuilderXD